# Css to javascript, making an animated arrow rotate in different conditions

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css animation for an arrow that rotates when a player wins or loses in a javascript game, how to I give the arrow a function in javascript to make it do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to swap your CSS animation in for a JS solution? What is the cSS animation that you already have? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: add a class and make that animation happen on that class